# When is 兄弟 interpreted as "siblings" and when is it interpreted as "brothers"?

Tags: words

I know that people often ask [兄弟]{きょうだい}いますか but does this mean "do you have siblings?" or just "do you have brothers?".

Since the answer would be different in either case:

(Has a sister) "No, but I have a sister" or would it be "Yes, I have a sister"
(Has a brother) "Yes I do"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say 兄弟いますか, it normally means "Do you have siblings?" (You'd say like お兄さんか弟(さん)いますか/いる？ to mean "Do you have brothers?") I think 兄弟(は)いますか？/兄弟(は)いる(の)？ will normally be responded with

> はい、姉/兄/妹/弟が(X人)います。
>   うん、お姉ちゃん/お兄ちゃん/妹/弟が(X人)いるよ。
>   はい、姉と弟がいます。

etc...

You'll say "No" when you're the only child:

> いいえ、一人っ子です。
>   ううん、一人っ子。

Comment: What about `兄弟姉妹` for asking about siblings?

Comment: ..and what about 姉妹 for asking for sisters?

Comment: I think 兄弟(か)姉妹はいますか is seen in formal situations or in the written style (eg. 相続, 法律関係...). When asking for sisters, I think you'd say like 「[女]{おんな}（の）[兄弟]{きょうだい}はいますか。」「お姉ちゃんか妹いる？」 in conversation.

Comment: As a side note, I've seen きょうだい (in hiragana) used to refer to 兄と妹 in the newspaper. I've also seen [兄妹]{きょうだい} and [姉弟]{きょうだい} (probably in a novel? essay? or newspaper).